# Using Embedded Glassfish with Maven

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, glassfish-embedded

Does anyone know anything about Embedded Glassfish? I want to run some of my EJB tests, but I do not want to start and stop the glassfish-embedded every time I run a test.

According to the plugin documentation I should put this in the POM :

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <app>target/ejbcontainer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</app>
                <name>test</name>
                <ports>
                    <http-listener>8080</http-listener>
                    <https-listener>8181</https-listener>
                </ports>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>  
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                        <goal>undeploy</goal>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This is all good. I can 'run' this embedded glassfish and I get this in my console which proves that its up and running :

> Information: test was successfully deployed in 1,124 milliseconds.
>   PlainTextActionReporterSUCCESSDescription: deploy AdminCommandApplication deployed with name test.
>       [name=test
>   Dec 16, 2013 6:03:29 PM PluginUtil doDeploy
>   Information: Deployed test
>   Hit ENTER to redeploy, X to exit

However when I 'Run' My Test files, ***a new instance*** of the embedded glassfish is created.

My test files are not picking up the currently running container.

Here is a Testfile if it helps :

```
public class Test extends TestCase {

    private Context ctx;
    private EJBContainer ejbContainer;

    public Test(String testName) {
        super(testName);
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();

        System.out.println("Opening the container");

        ctx = ejbContainer.getContext();
    }

    @AfterClass
    @Override
    public void tearDown() {
        ejbContainer.close();
        System.out.println("Closing the container");
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testApp() throws Exception {
        TemperatureConverter converter = (TemperatureConverter) ctx.lookup("java:global/classes/TemperatureConverter");
        assertNotNull(converter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just spotted this question as I've been playing around with embedded glassfish myself and having a few config issues, mainly related to logging output.

The way I use embedded glassfish for testing is to bind it to the Maven integration test phase e.g.

```
          <executions>
            <!-- Start embedded GlassFish -->
            <execution>
                <id>start</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>start</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>deploy</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>stop</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>undeploy</goal>
                    <goal>stop</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
```

And use the [Maven Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) to execute tests as part of the verify goal. These become more like integration tests though. If you name your test file with a suffix of IT e.g. myTestFileIT.java then they should be picked up automatically.

You can then run the tests by executing the following Maven command:

```
 mvn verify
```

I was originally using embedded Jetty which is where I had this setup working really well, I've found glassfish to be a bit more fiddly and quite time consuming to configure exactly as I require.

Hope this helps in some way with your problem.