# No EJBContainer provider available: no provider names had been found

Tags: junit, ejb

I'm getting the following exception on running a test case, for my service class.

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: No EJBContainer provider available: no provider names had been found.
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.reportError(EJBContainer.java:216)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:146)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Code:

```
public class NativeServiceTest {

       static NativeService NativeService;
       private static Context  ctx;
       private static EJBContainer ejbContainer;

       @BeforeClass
       public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

          ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();      
          ctx = ejbContainer.getContext();
       }


       @AfterClass
       public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
          ejbContainer.close();
        }


       @Test
       public void testGetCustomService() throws NamingException {
          Gson gson= new Gson();
          String id = "";
          NativeService converter = (NativeService) ctx.lookup("java:global/classes/NativeService");
          assertNotNull(converter);
          gson.fromJson(NativeService.getCustomService(id), Portlet.class);

       }
    }
```

NativeService.java

```
public class NativeService {

       @EJB
       DataService dataService;
       //
       //   
    }
```

I'm using `jta-data-source` for transaction.

Comment: Does your `NativeService` have with any Session Bean annotation?

Comment: Ok, so first you need to have a EJBContainerProvider implementation in your classpath. You could use [Glassfish embedded](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.main.extras/glassfish-embedded-all). Then, you need to annotate your `NativeService` with a session bean annotation in order to be able to look it up on the JNDI context.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: This post may also be applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616873/using-embedded-glassfish-with-maven as I was having a similar issue in NetBeans but since I was using maven, it didn't auto setup as the tutorial implied.

Answer (score 0):

`NativeService` needs to be an EJBBean, for example `@Stateless`. Also make sure the test is in the same project as the EJBBean.